# How can I get a DVD to play?

Tags: vlc, dvd

When I insert a DVD, videos said it cant be played. so i go into the disc and select a VOB file and that does not work.I’ve tried VLC and it still does not work. Please HELP!

Comment: what happens if you do Media/open disc in vlc? What VLC version you have? When was the last time that you updated the video codecs?

Answer (score 1):

Look for and install the following packages using Synaptic Package Manager:

- libdvdcss2
- libdvdread4
- libdvdnav4
- and any dependancies

Comment: also, install the QUICKTIME files.